# Scrapy ignore canonical url

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Is it possible to have scrapy to redirect pages containing a '[rel="canonical"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en&rd=1)' in their contents to the canonical url (if the page itself is not the canonical one)?

Comment: Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working.

Comment: I haven't code. If it possible to do that, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: But here is SO. I think you should Google you question first, then try the solution that you found. If you got an error, then you can ask question here. And I thought you know them.

Comment: I ask this question because, I found no solution when I should GG. May be, that I ask this question on the [scrapy-users - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scrapy-users)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built-in settings, but you can easily read the `meta rel=canonical` tag's value when one is around, and `response.follow()` the url if it's different from the current url.

Mind query arguments if any (and the odd hashbang on old sites). You might want to use this function when there are to double check that you're not about to `follow()` the same url:

https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.canonicalize_url

This middleware might also be useful:

https://gist.github.com/bcambel/4365237